Looker Studio Error - Metric results might not be accurate when using Asset level dimensions
I have a Looker Studio dashboard that was working with no issue before. For the past few months it shows the following error:
Metric results might not be accurate when using Asset level dimensions. Please add "Ad Type" and "Asset ID" fields to get accurate data.

I'm using blended data which is blending Google Sheets with Google Ads. This issue persists even if I add "Ad Type" and "Asset ID" to this data.
How can I either solve or hide this error? (at least hiding it would help getting rid of this annoying error).
I tried adding "Ad Type" and "Asset ID" to this data. Or Event rebuilding the tables joins by adding a new Google Ads to it so I get these fields from the new data source.
